# Axios post in react native throws property btoa does not exist error?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

when i execute axios post ,i am getting below error ,but when i add axios get , below registration process run without any issue. Any help would be highly appreciated.

> LOG  [ReferenceError: Property 'btoa' doesn't exist]

```
axios.post('https://........', {
  auth: {
    username: 'james',
    password: '123456'
  }

  }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
}).catch(function(error) {
console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2235

Comment: Thanks @Konrad  i have downgraded axios version to 0.18 and every thing works fine . May i ask why btoa does not exist any more in latest version and is it really best option to downgrade like i do

Comment: please bro ask to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76811800/how-to-make-rendering-video-in-pjsua2