# How to improve quality video for pjsua2 (pjsip) for android

Tags: java, android, sip, pjsua2, videocall

when working with video calls in android pjsua2 encountered the fact that the video is not rendered and pixels appear when the frame is changed

[image]

How to fix this problem. I am using this code to assign parameters to a codec.

```
codecParam.setEncFmt(
                setCodecParams(
                    codecParam.getEncFmt(), // MediaFormatVideo
                    30, // fpsNum
                    1, // fpsDenum
                    2048000, //AvgBps
                    10192000 // MaxBps
                )
  );


public MediaFormatVideo setCodecParams(
        MediaFormatVideo mediaFormatVideo,
        int fps,
        int fpsDeNum,
        int avgBps,
        int maxBps
    ) {
        mediaFormatVideo.setFpsNum(fps);
        mediaFormatVideo.setFpsDenum(fpsDeNum);
        if (avgBps > 0) {
            mediaFormatVideo.setAvgBps(avgBps);
        }
        if (maxBps > 0) {
            mediaFormatVideo.setMaxBps(maxBps);
        }
        mediaFormatVideo.setWidth(240);
        mediaFormatVideo.setHeight(320);


        return mediaFormatVideo;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. For best quality We need set decFmtp for codec param:

Set profile-level-id value for codec:

```
val codecFmtpVector = codecParam.decFmtp
for (i in codecFmtpVector.indices) {
     if ("profile-level-id" == codecFmtpVector[i].name) {
             codecFmtpVector[i].setVal("42e01f")
             break
     }
}
codecParam.decFmtp = codecFmtpVector
```